# Laravel 5.5 : WhereHas em relacionamento many to one

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

Pelo que eu entendi na documentação, para o *whereHas* funcionar é necessário ter um *get* no final da *query*, porém eu preciso usar o *first*, já que estou pegando as informações de um determinado registro. Do jeito que o código está, não apresenta nenhum erro, mas ele ignora o *where* dentro da *function* e acaba retornando todos resultados.

```
$serie = $this->serie->where('slug', $slug)
            ->whereHas('lista', function ($q){
                $q->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
            })
            ->first();
```

Se eu fizer mais uma *query*, funciona normal, mas gostaria de fazer tudo em uma só para ficar mais limpo o código.

```
$lista = Lista::where('serie_id', $serie->id)
        ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->first();
```

**MODEL SERIE**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Serie extends Model{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'series';
    protected $fillable = ['titulo', 'titulo_original', 'sinopse',
         'poster', 'data_lancamento', 'trailer', 'emissora_id', 
         'status', 'capa', 'slug'];
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function lista(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Lista');
    }
}
```

**MODEL LISTA**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Lista extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'listas';
    protected $fillable = ['descricao', 'serie_id', 'user_id'];
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function serie(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Serie');
    }
}
```

**SAIDA TOSQL**

```
select * from `series` where `slug` = ? and 
     exists (select * from `listas` 
              where `series`.`id` = `listas`.`serie_id` and `user_id` = ?)
```

Um usuário pode adicionar cada série a uma lista. Ele só pode ter cada série em uma lista somente. E uma serie pode estar na lista de todos usuários.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que faltou filtrar a lista mais interna, ou seja, a do relacionamento, é sempre bom fazer a carga com [with](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads), ***exemplo***:

```
$serie = $this->serie
        ->with(['lista' => function($q){
            $q->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
        }) 
        ->where('slug', $slug)
        ->whereHas('lista', function ($q){
            $q->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
        })
        ->first();
```

<sub>***Referencia:*** [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)</sub>